# Set background on TextView object and maintain ripple effect

Tags: android, background, android-imageview, textview, rippledrawable

I want to set the background of a TextView object programmatically, but also have a ripple effect for it.

I can use with background set to `android:selectableItemBackground`, but the ripple effect gets lost, when setting the background.

I also tried putting an `ImageView` together with the `TextView` in a `FrameLayout`. And set the image not as the background of the `TextView`, but as image of the `ImageView`: Yes, ripple is there, but it appears to be "behind" the image.

Do I need to create a `RippleDrawable` from the bitmapfor the background? How would I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem as you and fixed it using
`android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` on FrameLayout.

Here is the sample FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/discover_carousel_item_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know if `foreground` works in specific cases, but in my case I switched it to `background` and the View started displaying ripple effects when touched.

Answer (score 0):

RippleDrawable is the solution:

```
RippleDrawable newImage = new RippleDrawable(
        new ColorStateList(
                new int[][]{
                        new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                        new int[]{}
                },
                new int[] {
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_light),
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.ripple_material_dark),
                }),
                new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), mapBitmap),
                null);
textView.setBackground(newImage);
```

Comment: What is that `mapBitmap` argument in `BitmapDrawable` constructor?

Comment: That is a `Bitmap`. `RippleDrawable` is only available as of API version 21.