# Setting background drawable to TextView casues java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-drawable

I want to add some ripple effect with a png image in background of a TextView and found [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33477025/how-to-set-a-ripple-effect-on-textview-or-imageview-on-android/34128965#34128965)

I have action_darwer.xml drawable as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and setting it to TextView as

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/action_drawer"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/action_drawer"/>
```

it is not working at all and giving error

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
          at android.content.res.ColorStateList.valueOf(ColorStateList.java:102)
          at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:919)
          at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:914)
          at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.createConstantState(RippleDrawable.java:94)
          at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:126)
          at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.<init>(LayerDrawable.java:122)
          at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:979)
          at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.<init>(RippleDrawable.java:94)
          at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable$RippleState.newDrawable(RippleDrawable.java:945)
          at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawableLocked(Resources.java:2777)
          at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawable(Resources.java:2745)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2586)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1133)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1037)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2718)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1133)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1037)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2718)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1133)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1037)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2718)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1133)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1037)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2718)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1133)
          at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1037)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2718)
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2614)
          at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
          at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
        at android.graphi
02-16 13:12:53.567 22641-22641/org.team.asl.carticon E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
02-16 13:12:53.568 22641-22641/org.team.asl.carticon E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
      android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
          at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
          at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:504)
          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4294)
          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:89)
          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
          at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

how to solve this issue? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: show `drawable/drawer` code, or it is an image?

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes exactly that is an image!

Comment: Are you sure? can you post a screenshot of your resource folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

> StackOverflowError occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

At first modify **`background`**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/pressed/>  // Press State
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> // Focused
<item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer"/>  // Default State

</selector>
```

For more details check **[How can I modify ripple color when using ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33061050/how-can-i-modify-ripple-color-when-using-attr-selectableitembackground-as-backg)**

Comment: I need ripple effect in background so any drawable.xml file for that i.e pressed state

Comment: @ArshadAli http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27579626/set-background-on-textview-object-and-maintain-ripple-effect

Comment: @ArshadAli FYI another info,  `drawable` is not heavy size/resolution oriented

Answer (score 0):

As far as i am concerned, 
you cannot define 
?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless as drawable, thats where the crash is .
Change that to other drawable

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/drawer" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```